# Zend Framework: Multidb fails to initialize

Tags: apache, zend-framework, zend-db

This used to work but after some modifications by the other programmers it just fails to work. I have this code on my Bootstrap:

```
    protected function _initDatabase ()
{
    $resource = $this->getPluginResource('multidb');
    $resource->init();

    Zend_Registry::set('gtap', $resource->getDb('gtap'));
    Zend_Registry::set('phpbb', $resource->getDb('phpbb'));
}
```

Upon loading, this error shows up:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function init() on a non-object in
>   /var/www/gamebowl3/application/Bootstrap.php on line 105

My php.ini has this entry on tis include_path:

```
   .:/usr/share/php:/etc/apache2/libraries
```

and the i can see that multidb.php is located in:

```
/etc/apache2/librarties/Zend/Application/Resource
```

Can somebody tell me what causes the error? Thanks!

Comment: 99% $resource is null because maybe the method not work as you expected or maybe anything else...more code is needed.

Comment: @JhourladEstrella I am voting for you. It's the most I can do here for you :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found out that the problem is in application.ini. Added a newly-introduced setting to the usual set of configs. Here it is:

```
;Gtap Database
resources.multidb.gtap.adapter      = "PDO_MYSQL"
resources.multidb.gtap.host         = "localhost"
resources.multidb.gtap.username     = "root"
resources.multidb.gtap.password     = "letmein1"
resources.multidb.gtap.dbname       = "gtap"
resources.multidb.gtap.isDefaultTableAdapter = true
resources.multidb.gtap.default = true
;Forum Database
resources.multidb.phpbb.adapter     = "PDO_MYSQL"
resources.multidb.phpbb.host        = "localhost"
resources.multidb.phpbb.username    = "root"
resources.multidb.phpbb.password    = "letmein1"
resources.multidb.phpbb.dbname      = "phpbb"
resources.multidb.phpbb.isDefaultTableAdapter = false
```

Also, make sure you have the latest Zend Framework Library and add it to PHP's include path. That should fix everything up.