# Zend MultiDb resource

Tags: zend-framework

I have configured my application to work with multiple databases. The magic works just fine. In my Bootstrap.php I have defined the folowing:

```
protected function _initDb()
    {
        $resource = $this->getPluginResource('multidb');
        Zend_Registry::set("multidb", $resource);

    }
```

and in my application.ini:

```
resources.multidb.db1.adapter = mysqli
resources.multidb.db1.host = localhost
resources.multidb.db1.username = user
resources.multidb.db1.password = pass
resources.multidb.db1.dbname = db
resources.multidb.db1.charset= "utf8"
resources.multidb.db1.default= true
resources.multidb.db1.profiler.enabled = true

resources.multidb.oracle.adapter = oracle
resources.multidb.oracle.username = user
resources.multidb.oracle.password = pass
resources.multidb.oracle.charset= "utf8"
resources.multidb.oracle.dbname = "(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(Host = host.example.com) (Port = 1529)) (CONNECT_DATA = (SID = DB)))"
resources.multidb.oracle.profiler.enabled = true
```

All of this works just fine. In my models, I usually do something like this in the `init()`:

```
$multidb = Zend_Registry::get("multidb");
$this->oracle = $multidb->getDb('oracle');
```

But I recently wanted to move this part to the Bootstrap, or rather, Registry, like this:

```
protected function _initDb()
    {
        $resource = $this->getPluginResource('multidb');
        Zend_Registry::set("multidb", $resource);
        Zend_Registry::set("odb",$resource->getDb('oracle'));
    }
```

And this is what happened:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Application_Resource_Exception' with message 'A DB adapter was tried to retrieve, but was not configured' in C:\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\Zend\Application\Resource\Multidb.php on line 135
```

I know a temporary fix around this, but why is this happening, and what could be a more long term fix, so that I could set each adapter in registry, preferably in bootstrap?
Thanks!

Comment: Thats the Zend library. I havent tampered with it.

Comment: `public function getDb($db = null)
    {
        if ($db === null) {
            return $this->getDefaultDb();
        }

        if (isset($this->_dbs[$db])) {
            return $this->_dbs[$db];
        }

        throw new Zend_Application_Resource_Exception(
            'A DB adapter was tried to retrieve, but was not configured'
        );
    }` The exception throwing is on 135

Comment: Does this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7924440/zend-framework-multidb-fails-to-initialize/7924560#7924560 solve your problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you have to make sure the multidb resource is bootstrapped in other to be filled. You can do this with the following:

```
protected function _initDb() {         
    $this->bootstrap('multidb');

    $resource = $this->getPluginResource('multidb');         

    Zend_Registry::set("multidb", $resource);         
    Zend_Registry::set("odb",$resource->getDb('oracle'));     
}
```

Comment: Perfect. Worked like a charm. Could you please explain what bootstrapping is? Or point me in the direction of some helpful articles?

Comment: In the above example your bootstrap method _initDb has a dependency to the multidb application resource. Thanks to this bootstrapping system it's possible to load dependencies for a other resource by calling $this->bootstrap(resource). I think this: http://goo.gl/RIwzA and/or http://goo.gl/DWiPY article will help you out. This article might help you as well: http://goo.gl/XIwFx